# Помогите правильно построить mysql запрос

Tags: mysql

Помогите правильно создать запрос mysql.

Есть таблица из двух колонок: дата | IP адрес
Нужно посчитать сколько в определенный день есть строк с каждым IP адресом.

Например смотрим дату 25/06/2019.

Результат:
25.06.2019 192.168.0.1 - 20
25.06.2019 192.168.0.2 - 15
25.06.2019 192.168.0.3 - 10

где 20,15,10 - это сколько раз данный IP адрес встречается в таблице за 25.06.2019

Comment: WHERE + GROUP BY + COUNT()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

таблица

```
+----++----+
|date|| ip |
+----++----+
```

Получается:

```
SELECT date, ip, COUNT(ip) as qty FROM `your_table` GROUP BY date, ip
```